# How to access the variable in panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
for col_name in df.columns: 
    if col_name=='SalePrice':
        continue
    if df.col_name.dtype=="O":
        one_hot = pd.get_dummies(df.col_name)
       
        df = df.drop(col_name,axis = 1)
         
        df = df.join(one_hot)
```

**AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col_name'
Is this syntax wrong??**

Comment: Try `df[col_name]`

Comment: replace the col_name with the actual __column_name__

Comment: @Aditya he will have to write separate statement for all the columns he has to drop

Comment: There's a much cleaner way to do what the o/p wants; Simply filter the dtypes for the one you are looking for; This might lead to mem explosion;

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass variable for column_name in `data.column_name` due to syntactical limitations.

```
for col_name in df.columns: 
    if col_name=='SalePrice':
        continue
    if df[col_name].dtype=="O":
        one_hot = pd.get_dummies(df[col_name])
   
        df = df.drop(col_name,axis = 1)
     
        df = df.join(one_hot)
```

This should work fine.

Comment: it give error on df=df.join(one_hot),  error->columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Gd'], dtype='object') , how can resolove it??